# Problems running Conda

Tags: python, zsh, jupyter, conda

Every time I try to use `conda` in my terminal I get this error:

`zsh: correct 'conda' to '.conda' [nyae]?`

I have added `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda/bin` to my `.zshrc` and to my `.bash_profile` files.

Now, if I run `source ~/.bash_profile` it works, but I have to run this command every time I open a new window. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `zsh`'s error message means `conda` is not in the path, but it does see anaconda's `.conda` folder in your user directory. There is most likely a line in `.bash_profile` that puts `conda` in your `$PATH` that your line in `.zshrc` doesn't do. What are the relevant lines in `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Can you put anaconda at the front of your PATH instead of the end?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, so I copy the coda initialize code from my .bashrc to .zshrc and it worked.

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/path/to/ur/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/path/to/ur/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/path/to/ur/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/path/to/ur/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```